# C++ select from a vector of objects

Tags: c++, stl, lambda

I have a class A with the following member method:

```
bool A::test();
```

I have a `vector<A> v` of A objects. I would like to create a new `vector<A>` 
from v, selecting only those elements for which A::test() returns true.

What is the simplest and most elegant way to do this using STL and boost::lambda (I
do not have C++11) ?

Comment: Unfortunately `copy_if` did not make it into C++03 due to an oversight.

Answer (score 4):

While `copy_if` didn't make it into the earlier standard, you can accomplish the same thing with `remove_copy_if`.

And if you have C++11 available, it's trivially simple:

```
std::remove_copy_if(
      v.begin(),
      v.end(),
      std::back_inserter(b),
      [] (const A& val) -> bool
      { return val.test(); });
```

Since you don't have C++11, still easy:

```
// global free function
bool test_a(const A& a) { return a.test(); }

std::remove_copy_if(
      v.begin(),
      v.end(),
      std::back_inserter(b),
      test_a);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why use back_inserter(b) and not b.begin() ? What is the difference ?

Comment: You use a `back_inserter` because that specifically will "push back" elements into our container.  `remove_copy_if` will overwrite the contents at the destination iterator, so we would have to resize `b` prior to calling this function, but we don't know beforehand what to resize it to.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `remove_copy_if` to do this, something like `std::remove_copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(new_v), pred_that_returns_true_when_A::test()_is_false);`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
std::vector<A>::iterator testFailedIt = std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), test());
std::copy(v.begin(), testFailedIt, std::back_inserter(newVector));
```

If you don't care about the relative order of the elements, std::partition can do, too.

std::partition/stable_partition reorder the elements in a sequence such that the items for which test() is true are in the first part of the sequence, and the others are in the second part of the sequence. It returns an iterator to the first position of the second group.

Answer (score 0):

How about going the reverse way? Make a copy of the first vector and use remove_if. You just need to reverse your test function's return value. Something like this:

```
std::vector<A> second_vector(first_vector);
std::erase(std::remove_if(second_vector.begin(), second_vector.end(), test), second_vector.end());
```

Comment: Remember that you have to `erase` the space no longer used after calling `remove_if`.